# Python: From Rows to Columns for Specific Sections in DF

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have the following table in excel which looks as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

data = """  Col1  |  Col2  |  Col3  | Col4 
 Value11 | Value21 | Value31 |      
 stuff  | stuff  | stuff  |  2.0 
 stuff  | stuff  | stuff  |  3.0 
        |        | Total  |  5.0 
 Value12 | Value22 | Value32 |      
 stuff  | stuff  | stuff  |  6.0 
 stuff  | stuff  | stuff  |  4.0 
        |        | Total  | 10.0 """

df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data), header=0, delimiter = "|")

print(df)

+---------+---------+---------+------+
|  Col1   |  Col2   |  Col3   | Col4 |
+---------+---------+---------+------+
| Value11 | Value21 | Value31 |      |
| stuff   | stuff   | stuff   |  2.0 |
| stuff   | stuff   | stuff   |  3.0 |
|         |         | Total   |  5.0 |
| Value12 | Value22 | Value32 |      |
| stuff   | stuff   | stuff   |  6.0 |
| stuff   | stuff   | stuff   |  4.0 |
|         |         | Total   | 10.0 |
+---------+---------+---------+------+
```

and would like to have like this so that I can do data analysis:

```
+-------+-------+--------+------+----------+---------+---------+
| Col1  | Col2  |  Col3  | Col4 |   Col5   |  Col6   |  Col7   |
+-------+-------+--------+------+----------+---------+---------+
| stuff | stuff | stuff  |  2.0 | Value11  | Value21 | Value31 |
| stuff | stuff | stuff  |  3.0 | Value11  | Value21 | Value31 |
| stuff | stuff | stuff  |  6.0 | Value12  | Value22 | Value32 |
| stuff | stuff | stuff  |  4.0 | Value12  | Value22 | Value32 |
+-------+-------+--------+------+----------+---------+---------+
```

That is, I would like to turn the Values in each of the Col1,Col2,Col3 into repeating rows next to their corresponding section.

The only pattern I see is that there is a "Total" variable in Col3 just above the values I want to turn into rows.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this in Python?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Col1": ["Value11", "stuff1", "stuff1","Value12", "stuff2", "stuff2"],
     "Col2": ["Value21", "stuff1", "stuff1","Value22", "stuff2", "stuff2"],
     "Col3": ["Value31", "stuff1", "stuff1","Value32", "stuff2", "stuff2"],
     "Col4": ["", 2, 3,"",6,4], },
    index=[1, 2, 3,4,5,6])

df1 = df.loc[df['Col1'] == 'stuff1']
df2 = df.loc[df['Col1'] == 'stuff2']

dfc = pd.concat([df1,df2])

df11 = df.loc[df['Col1'] == 'Value11']
df22 = df.loc[df['Col1'] == 'Value12']


dfc1 = pd.concat([df11, df11])
dfc2 = pd.concat([df22, df22])



df_fin1 = pd.concat([dfc1, dfc2])

print(df_fin1)
dfc.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df_fin1.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df_fin = pd.concat([dfc, df_fin1], axis=1)


print(df_fin)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Chris. That is not really what I am looking for, I do not know what the value11,value12 are in advance, neither do I know what "stuff" is, the only consistent variable is total, which is just above the value11, value22 that I want

Comment: if you know the specific row your data is located, just selected those rows/columns and manipulate them?

Comment: The problem is that I do not know the specific location of the data, I only know that the Values I want to have as columns are always above the rows which contain a value called "Total", which is the only consistent pattern I have unfortunately

Comment: Check for rows with "Total" in it and run my second code snippet on every row above the "Total" row. If you have done that, check for a second "Total" row and do the same. It's a for loop. There may be a more efficient method but that would get the job done

Comment: Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Yes, but its not the total row I want, its the row below it and make it a column next the section to which it belongs

Answer (score 0):

So if you only select the rows and manipulate them, it code looks like this:

```
df21 = pd.concat([df.iloc[0:1], df.iloc[0:1]])
df22 = pd.concat([df.iloc[4:5], df.iloc[4:5]])

df2 = pd.concat([df21,df22])

df1 = pd.concat([df.iloc[1:3], df.iloc[5:7]])

df1.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df2.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df_f = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```